# Matlab ... character in string split - How to remove?

Tags: string, matlab, io, char

Question is pretty simple but I can't google up the single character '...' in matlab.

```
DELIMS = {' ', '.', ',', '?', '\n'};
email = fileread(file_path);
email = strsplit(email, DELIMS);
```

That's all. Originally, the string looks like:

"Subject: 87 , 847 bottles sold daily - slze matters ! 6 ppntufbis
aqtdaibnuf jmxdzjdyjskm noyrhrcsltyiyc yfcgqhbjrw noqqngttnymi ljpdpfbocwqnjb
the only solution to ..." and it continues. I won't post the rest because this is about a male enhancement drug spam email.

When I split on this string, I get the following:

```
Columns 1 through 4

'Subject:'    '87'    '847'    'bottles'

Columns 5 through 8

'sold'    'daily'    '-'    'slze'

Columns 9 through 12

'matters'    '!'    '6'    'ppntufbis…'

Columns 13 through 14

'aqtdaibnuf'    'jmxdzjdyjskm'

Columns 15 through 16

'noyrhrcsltyiyc'    'yfcgqhbjrw'

Columns 17 through 18

'noqqngttnymi'    'ljpdpfbocwqnjb…'
```

Upon inspection, we see these … characters that are really one character. I'm assuming these are \n characters(which I should have removed). I want to get rid of these but since google doesn't recognize these characters as actual queries I'm a bit lost as to what these are. Coming from a C++ background, this is very confusing. Any help would be appreciated!

```
whos email
Name       Size             Bytes  Class    Attributes

email      1x125            15252  cell 


email{12}

ans =

ppntufbis


char(email{12})

ans =

ppntufbis
```

Comment: It looks to be the unicode [horizontal ellipsis](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm) character.

Comment: I can't reproduce with R20105b using the exact example string in your text. What Matlab version do you use?

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm using R2016b. and beaker, is a potential solution to cast from unicode? Perhaps it's because of the file's format itself. I can send you it but I can't really post the file online on stack overflow.

Comment: I can't test it right now on R2016b. After `strsplit`, what do `email{12}`, `char(email{12})` and `whos email` show?

Comment: @LuisMendo just updated question.

Comment: Let's see if someone with R2016b can reproduce. It's weird that the `…` doesn't show in `email{12}` but it shows when displaying the whole cell array. Perhaps it's an R2016b display thing

Comment: @LuisMendo it actually also does not work when trying to search as a key in a hash map in matlab. This is where I found the bug.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with R2016b.  The stray ellipsis characters can't be found in my output. P.S. Come back to the MATLAB chat room! We miss you.

Comment: @rayryeng omg hi ray! I've visited a couple times but you weren't there :( I can send you the email if you want haha.

Answer (score 2):

So with beaker's help, I was able to find out the solution.

'...' is actually Matlab's way of telling me there's more after what's seen, specifically the next line(may it be empty or not).

When I specified my own delimiters, I thought I included the newline character \n, but this file is so old that it was using `\f`. Matlab didn't tell me otherwise so I thought I was actually able to split on lines.